# How can we give READ access to a particular resource while putting condition on some other resource in ACL file?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

What I want to do is that give READ ACCESS to a particular participant the fields of other participants but putting condition on third resource.

Eg:

```
rule SampleRule{
       description: "Allow the Participant1 to view Participant2 profile"
       participant(m): "org.sample.blockchain.Participant1"
       operation: READ
       resource(v): "org.sample.blockchain.Participant2"
       condition:(
                  v.getIdentifier() == Record.Participant1.getIdentifier() 
                     && m.getIdentifier() == Record.Participant2.getIdentifier()
                )
       action: ALLOW
    }
    asset Record identified by Id {
       o String Id
       --> Participant1 Participant1
       --> Participant2 Participant2
    }
    participant Participant1 identified by EmailId{
       o String EmailId
       o String Name
       o Integer Age
    }
    participant Participant2 identified by EmailId{
       o String EmailId
       o String Name
       o Integer Age
    }
```

So here I want to give access of profile of participant2 to participant1 based on some asset record.

Is it possible to this thing in composer and if not what are the other options?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is currently possible with Hyperledger Composer. You cannot look up an unrelated asset from within an ACL rule.

However, you can look up the identifier of a related asset. To make this possible, you would need to add a relationship from the participant to the record as follows:

```
asset Record identified by Id {
    o String Id
    --> Participant1 Participant1
    --> Participant2 Participant2
}

participant Participant1 identified by EmailId{
    o String EmailId
    o String Name
    o Integer Age
    --> Record record // note the new record field
}
```

You can then access the related `record` field from an ACL rule:

```
rule SampleRule {
    description: "Allow the Participant1 to view Participant2 profile"
    participant(m): "org.sample.blockchain.Participant1"
    operation: READ
    resource(v): "org.sample.blockchain.Participant2"
    condition: (
        m.record.getIdentifier() === v.record.getIdentifier()
    )
    action: ALLOW
}
```

We have a GitHub issue at the moment to resolve the relationships to related assets, which will allow you to look up all fields of a related asset:

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1007

Comment: Hey Simon, I am curious if there are any updates on that topic with composer version `v0.20.5`? The thing is that with your approach of referencing the `Record` object in the `Participant1` resource, at creation time of a `Participant1` instance the `Record` instance has also to be created; unless you make it optional. Is this right? If that's the case and you make it optional, then you have to be aware and update the reference in `Participant1` if the `Record` is created... seems a bit inconvenient, since there are references resolving relations, why not also resolving on other resources?